# Middleman application Build error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, middleman

When I try to build with middleman I am getting the following error:

```
YAML Exception: (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 2 column 31
```

I am not able to find it even i have tried with the --verbose something like this:

```
bundle exec middleman build -c --verbose
```

there is same result if i don't use --verbose. Can anyone tell how i can i figure out where the error is.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Could be bad syntax in one of your data/*.yml files or YAML frontmatter.

Do you see any filename of your own (data/…, source/…) close to the "YAML Exception" in the stack trace?

If you have data/*.yml files, you can validate them to find errors. If you have YAML frontmatter sections, you can try removing them one at a time and running `build` again.